# Select all files except one extension

Tags: c#, regex

I want to delete files by their file extensions in a directory. Right now my program simply chooses all files types with the filter "dot asterisk", like so:

```
.*
```

I now need it to delete all files except for files with the *.abc* file extension.  How would I change the regex filter to reflect this?

Comment: Show you code, or it's hard to say.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions.  I tested thoroughly, but I could not get any of them to work.  I do believe it is an issue with my program and not your code suggestions.

Comment: Michael didn't mention that this is a tool which takes a regex in a field to select files which are going to be deleted. Michael cannot change the tool as its not his. I also use the tool. The app is written in .net and runs though the files in a given path and deletes all, say, all files in a temp directory. Michael wants the tool to delete all temp files *except*, say .out files.

Answer (score 2):

Or, the most simply:

```
(?i)\.abc$
```

Don't even need a fancy regex engine (with lookaround support) to match that one. Just negate the match in your code. If it matches, don't delete it. If not, delete it.

The `(?i)` part is optional. It makes the regex case-insensitive (so it'll match *file1.abc* and *FILE2.ABC*). You can achieve the same effect with [Regex options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5845fdz.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Negative <strike>look-ahead</strike> look-behind (assuming the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) you're referring to supports it):

```
^.*(?<!\.abc)$
```

*Sorry, you want look-behind, not ahead.*

Comment: @Bohemian: yea, caught it. Approaching bed time. [Should work now.](http://regexr.com?32ij6) ;-)

Comment: That looks like being a good solution. I've just been trying this out on a dot net regex evaluator on the web using the following ^.*(?<!\.out)(?<!\.log)$ and it seem to correctly match everything I throw at it, except .log and .out

Comment: yep, just tried it out in the same tool as Michael uses and it works for me. I had attempted this myself and had gotten close, but not quite right. I had been trying look ahead without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative look behind, anchored to the end of input, like so:

```
^.*(?<!\.abc)$
```

Or more simply use a negative look ahead anchored to start of input:

```
^(?!.*\.abc$)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just that we also have a reply with a "real" regex:

```
(^.?.?.?|[^.]...|\.[^a]..|\..[^b].|\...[^c])$
```

However you can see that this gets very complicated, especially when you need a second extension, so you actually really want to use some of the other solutions :-)

Comment: I can't see how this will work. I can't really even see what you are trying to do here. The second alternate (`[^.]...`) will fail for *file.xaml* and this will incorrectly reject *file.acd* (should only reject *file.abc*).

Comment: You didn't try it, did you? Here's how it works: The first alternative handles 3 or less chars strings. The other four ones are constructed such that the only string which maches *none* of the four is the string `.abc`. For example, `.axc` matches `\..[^b].` and `-abc` matches `[^.]...` - as they are ORed, that's enough. Only `.abc` fails to match any of them, because for all alternatives, it has the forbidden char at exactly the position where the `[^x]` is.

Comment: Ah... I see it now. My mistake. Talk about hard to maintain. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple `regex`:

```
^.*(?=[.]abc$)
```

explain:

> ***`^`***
> The match must start at the beginning of the string or line.
>
> ***`(?= subexpression)`***
> Zero-width positive lookahead assertion.
>
> ***`[ character_group ]`***
> Matches any single character in character_group.
>
> ***`$`***
> The match must occur at the end of the string or before `\`n at the end of the line or string.